# Windows use different php version instead the

Tags: php, windows

I have php 8.1 and php 8.2 on my computer, in the Environment Variables I set php 8.2 in first position:

[image: Php 8.2 is in top position]

But windows terminal continue to use php 8.1

If I run `php -i` php 8.1.10 still be there, but no trace inside the environment variables.

```
Path => C:\Python311\Scripts\;
C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64;
C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.2.7-Win32-vs16-x64;C:\laragon\bin;
```

Where is stored? The only way to make php 8.2 work still rename the php 8.1 folder

(I restart my pc many times)

Comment: If you print PATH from terminal you get the expected value? What happens if you run `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\php -v` from that same terminal?

Comment: In PATH I got the same, php 8.1 before php 8.2, If I run php -v inside the php 8.1.10 folder I got PHP 8.1.10 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2022 18:05:49) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Comment: What happens if you run `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\php -v` from that same terminal

Comment: `C:\Users\StefanoMartini>C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\php -v
PHP 8.1.10 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2022 18:05:49) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies`

Comment: Arggg, sorry, I messed versions. You want 8.2. If PATH has 8.1 before, you aren't setting path correctly. I remind you that there're two settings in the interface: "User variables" and "System variables". It's easier if you only set PHP in one of the groups.

Comment: Yes! I didn't see that! I had php 8.1 in system variables!